# STM32H7 I2S Switching from a Fws 96kHz to 48kHz everything stops working, why?

Tags: stm32, i2s

everyday something new with this board.

I recently discovered I was in the wrong Fws to implement my IIR filters as discussed in a previous question I posted.

The solution is essentially step down my Fws from 96kHz to 48kHz. So I did, now the [I2S device](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual)  or the [MCU](https://www.google.com/search?q=stm32h753zi&oq=stm32h7&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0j35i39l2j0i20i263i457j69i60l3.6982j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) doesn't want to transmit or receive anymore. **Do note the only piece of code change is to get the SPI clock to 61.44MHz from 98.34004MHz thats all.**

I'll shall even post the difference in code from the 98kHz varient to the 48kHz varient.

When I switch back to 96kHz everything works again.

The steps I took to troubleshoot.

- Ensure the clocks are what they are suppose to:
- DIVP2: 10
- DIVN2: 48
- DIVM2: 5
- Probed the PMOD device to ensure it's seeing the right clocks. Checked.
- Used the oscilloscope to see if the right clocks are being outputted:
- MCLK = ~12.3MHz
- SCLK = ~3.086MHz
- FWS = ~48.18kHz
- Checked if the ratios are inline with the PMOD datasheet to get the right sampling rate
- MCLK/LRCK(Fws) = ~255
- SCLK/LRCK(Fws) = ~64
- Checked the math if my Fws and MLCK are correct:

Clock Pictures when Fws = 48kHz

Signal: Fws
[image]
Signal: MCLK
[image]
Signal: SCLK
[image]

96kHz code:

```
void init_I2S(){

    //Setting Clock for 98.304MHz
    //N = 122
    //P = 8
    //M = 10
    //FRACT = 7209

    // RCC_PLL2DIVR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2;
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2_DIV8; // P
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2_MULT122; // N

    // RCC_PLLCKSELR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_DIV10; // M

    // RCC_PLL2FRACR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL2FRACR &= ~RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL2FRACR |= RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN_7209; // FRAC

    // RCC_PLLCFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE_4_8;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL_192_836;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;

    // RCC_CR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WAITING:
    while (((RCC -> CR) & (RCC_CR_PLL2RDY)) == 0){};

    // ENALBING CLOCKS

    // RCC_AHB4ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;

    // RCC_APB2ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR &= ~RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

    // CHANGING CLOCKS OF PERIPHERALS
    // RCC_D2CCIP1R
    // MASKING;
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R &= ~RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R |=  RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL_PLL2_P_CK;

    // CHANGING GPIO PINS TO ALETERNATIVE
    // GPIOx_MODER
    // MASKING
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE5;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE6;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7;
    GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    // WRITING:
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE7_ALT;
    GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;

    //SETTING ALT FUNCTIONS TO PINS
    // GPIOx_AFRL
    // MASKING:
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    // WRITING;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_AF5;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;

    // ENABLING DMA1
    // RCC_AHB1ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR &= ~RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;

    // SETTING UP DMA FOR I2S
    // DMAMUX1_Channel0_CCR
    // DMAMUX1_Channel1_CCR
    // NOTE: Using DMAMUX1 -> DMA1_Channel 0 & 1
    // 0x25 = Rx | 0x26 = Tx
    // MASKING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    // WRITING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI1_Rx; //Rx
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI1_Tx; //Tx

    // DMA1_Stream0_CR
    // DMA1_Stream1_CR
    // MASKING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_P_TO_M;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_M_TO_P;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;

    // DMA_SxNDTR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> NDTR = 0x4;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> NDTR = 0x4;

    // DMA_SxPAR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> PAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->RXDR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> PAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->TXDR;

    // DMA_SxM0AR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> M0AR = (int32_t)RxBuff;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> M0AR = (int32_t)TxBuff;

    // DMA_SxCR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;
    DMA1_Stream1 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

    // Setting up the SPI/I2S Peripheral
    // MASKING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CHLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_FTHLV;

    // WRITING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD_MULT2;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV_2;

    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV_I2S;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATALEN_24BIT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL_FALL_RISE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD_I2STAND;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CHNEL_32BIT_WIDE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG_MASTER_FULLDUPLEX;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD_I2S_PCM_MODE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT_LAlign;
    //SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_CFG1_FTHLV_2_Data;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART;

}
```

48kHz Code:

```
void init_I2S(){

    //Setting Clock for 98.304MHz
    //N = 48
    //P = 10
    //M = 5
    //FRACT = 0

    // RCC_PLL2DIVR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2;
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2_DIV10; // P
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2_MULTI48; // N

    // RCC_PLLCKSELR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_DIV5; // M

    // RCC_PLL2FRACR
    // MASKING:
    //RCC -> PLL2FRACR &= ~RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN2;
    // WRITING:
    //RCC -> PLL2FRACR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_DIV5; // FRAC

    // RCC_PLLCFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL;
    //RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE_8_16;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL_192_836;
    //RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;

    // RCC_CR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WAITING:
    while (((RCC -> CR) & (RCC_CR_PLL2RDY)) == 0){};

    // ENALBING CLOCKS

    // RCC_AHB4ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;

    // RCC_APB2ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR &= ~RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

    // CHANGING CLOCKS OF PERIPHERALS
    // RCC_D2CCIP1R
    // MASKING;
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R &= ~RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R |=  RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL_PLL2_P_CK;

    // CHANGING GPIO PINS TO ALETERNATIVE
    // GPIOx_MODER
    // MASKING
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE5;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE6;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7;
    GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    // WRITING:
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE7_ALT;
    GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;

    //SETTING ALT FUNCTIONS TO PINS
    // GPIOx_AFRL
    // MASKING:
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    // WRITING;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_AF5;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;

    // ENABLING DMA1
    // RCC_AHB1ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR &= ~RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;

    // SETTING UP DMA FOR I2S
    // DMAMUX1_Channel0_CCR
    // DMAMUX1_Channel1_CCR
    // NOTE: Using DMAMUX1 -> DMA1_Channel 0 & 1
    // 0x25 = Rx | 0x26 = Tx
    // MASKING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    // WRITING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI1_Rx; //Rx
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI1_Tx; //Tx

    // DMA1_Stream0_CR
    // DMA1_Stream1_CR
    // MASKING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_P_TO_M;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_M_TO_P;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;

    // DMA_SxNDTR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> NDTR = 0x4;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> NDTR = 0x4;

    // DMA_SxPAR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> PAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->RXDR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> PAR = (int32_t)&SPI1->TXDR;

    // DMA_SxM0AR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> M0AR = (int32_t)RxBuff;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> M0AR = (int32_t)TxBuff;

    // DMA_SxCR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;
    DMA1_Stream1 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

    // Setting up the SPI/I2S Peripheral
    // MASKING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CHLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_FTHLV;

    // WRITING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD_ADD1;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV_2;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV_I2S;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATALEN_24BIT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL_FALL_RISE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD_I2STAND;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CHNEL_32BIT_WIDE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG_MASTER_FULLDUPLEX;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD_I2S_PCM_MODE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT_LAlign;
    //SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_CFG1_FTHLV_2_Data;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART;

}
```

UPDATE 1: Just tried changing FWS = 192kHz doesnt work either.

UPDATE 2:

It works when using i2s_clk as 49.152MHz and not the 61.44MHz still doesnt answer anything. Suspecting could it be the voltage range?